# Extraneous inflection behavior on SQL Server full-text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Searching certain words (e.g. `agarte`) using `CONTAINS` on a table with only one row and one text field with only one word (e.g. `te`), SQL Server find that row as valid result. (*I'm looking for `agarte` and `te` is valid?*)

I've tested on two different SQL Server 2008 and other SQL Server 2012 at different servers.

**I think is related with inflectional forms but I cannot understand why and how modify this behavior.**

One complete runnable test is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
SELECT version = @@VERSION
GO
CREATE TABLE foo (k int identity(1,1), f nvarchar(max) not null, CONSTRAINT PK_foo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (k ASC))
GO
INSERT INTO foo (f) VALUES ('te')
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG foo_catalog
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON foo(f) KEY INDEX PK_foo ON foo_catalog WITH STOPLIST = OFF
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG foo_catalog REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
GO
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
GO
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"agarte"', language 3082) -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"egarte"', language 3082) -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"ogarte"', language 3082) -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"garte"' , language 3082) -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"gurte"' , language 3082) -- 0
GO
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON foo
GO
DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG foo_catalog
GO
DROP TABLE foo
GO
```

I'm going to set neutral language on searchs as workaround but I would like understand why and how control this behavior. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be the wordbraker

If we run

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser (' "ugarte" ', 3082, 0, 0)
```

get

```
keyword                    group_id phrase_id occurrence special_term display_term expansion_type source_term
-------------------------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------ ------------ -------------- -----------
0x0075006700610072         1        0         1          Exact Match  ugar         0              ugarte
0x00740065                 1        0         1          Noise Word   te           0              ugarte
0x007500670061007200740065 1        0         1          Exact Match  ugarte       0              ugarte
```

with `ogorte` and others not occur.

Without down to `IFilter` looks not possible avoid that word break.

Related information:

- [Configure and Manage Word Breakers and Stemmers for Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx)
- [Getting a custom IFilter working with SQL Server 2008/R2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlfts/2011/07/13/getting-a-custom-ifilter-working-with-sql-server-2008r2-ifiltersample/)